# VPN Information for Azure VM

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have set up a new virtual machine and added it to a virtual network.

Now my difficulty is what will be the VPN Peer IP Address I'll share with clients? Is it the public IP of my virtual machine?

Also the VPN host IP address? Is that the public IP as well?  All these have me confused as I have to provide them to our clients.

Where can I find these info on Azure?

Comment: what kind of VPN connection do you want to establish? Site2Site or End2End?

Comment: @gapvision Site2site, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create two Gateways for a Site-to-Site VPN connections:

1) a Virtual Gateway which will serve es public endpoint for the other site (network)

2) a Local Gateway which "mocks" the public endpoint of the other site (network)

It is explained quite good here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal/ - You need to check the compatibilities between Azure and the VPN device (check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices/)

Comment: This hit the nail on the head for me. Thanks.